How does LangChain implement a mechanism where a particular tool must be used at the first call step before generating an answer?
I can't use the following method to implement that mechanism; this code can lead to consistent calling.
always_call_tool_llm = llm.bind_tools([add, multiply], tool_choice="any")

I tried a lot of methods, but I suspect LangChain didn't offer this mechanism.
